# relative layout bottom buttons goes up

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout with scrollview. In My relative layout i have few image buttons and radio group when i select the radio option the bottom image view `android:id="@+id/sol_btn`
goes up.

Why its goes up? what mistake in my layout? And in my manifest also i have used this

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

My layout code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".Quesans">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/que_txt"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
             android:text="TextView" />
        <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/image"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/que_txt"
             android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/que_txt"/>
         <RadioGroup
             android:id="@+id/rdgroup"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/image"
             android:orientation="vertical" >
         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/RB1" 
             android:text=""/>
         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/RB2" 
             android:text=""/>
         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/RB3" 
             android:text=""/>
         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/RB4" 
             android:text=""/>
        </RadioGroup>
        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/rdtxt"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/rdgroup"
             android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
             android:text="Nothing is picked" 
             android:textColor="#0000FF"/>
        <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/nxt_btn"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/rdtxt"
             android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
             android:src="@drawable/next_pressed" />
         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/focusarea"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nxt_btn"
             android:layout_below="@+id/nxt_btn"
             android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:src="@drawable/focusarea_pressed" />
         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/app"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
             android:src="@drawable/newapps" />
         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/prv_btn"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nxt_btn"
             android:src="@drawable/previous_pressed" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/sol_btn"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/prv_btn"
             android:layout_below="@+id/prv_btn"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
             android:src="@drawable/solution_pressed" />

     </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you post your java code?

Comment: have u declared `padding` in `drawable/solution_pressed` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Solution Button(@+id/sol_btn) having Margin 10 dp to the previous button(@+id/prv_btn).,
So For the First question since the previous button will not be in the view your Solution button is going to the top of the view.

> > So Make the visibility of the previous button from View.Gone to View.Invisible.

Your problem will be solved:-

Answer (score 3):

I have changed images to default. Edit xml file and try this,it will work fine.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/que_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/que_txt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/que_txt"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rdgroup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RB1"
                android:text="" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RB2"
                android:text="" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RB3"
                android:text="" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RB4"
                android:text="" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rdtxt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rdgroup"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Nothing is picked"
            android:textColor="#0000FF" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/focusarea"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nxt_btn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nxt_btn"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sol_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/prv_btn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/prv_btn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/prv_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rdtxt"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nxt_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/prv_btn"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It shows error Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Comment: have you changed properly images (ic_launcher) to desired images? Please check again. XML is running fine from my side on Samsung SII and Galaxy Nexus One.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     tools:context=".Quesans">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/que_txt"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
         android:text="TextView" />
    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/que_txt"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/que_txt"/>
     <RadioGroup
         android:id="@+id/rdgroup"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/image"
         android:orientation="vertical" >
     <RadioButton 
         android:id="@+id/RB1" 
         android:text=""/>
     <RadioButton 
         android:id="@+id/RB2" 
         android:text=""/>
     <RadioButton 
         android:id="@+id/RB3" 
         android:text=""/>
     <RadioButton 
         android:id="@+id/RB4" 
         android:text=""/>
    </RadioGroup>
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/rdtxt"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/rdgroup"
         android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
         android:text="Nothing is picked" 
         android:textColor="#0000FF"/>
    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/nxt_btn"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/rdtxt"
         android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/focusarea"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nxt_btn"
         android:layout_below="@+id/nxt_btn"
         android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/app"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/prv_btn"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nxt_btn"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/sol_btn"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/prv_btn"
         android:layout_below="@+id/prv_btn"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:focusable=false` on your `RadioGroup`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` from your menifest. I have done like this.. It is not go up.

Comment: i have removed now also it goes up

Comment: Have you put an Animation on It :D :D :D??